# When did m4 get a comment feature? And why?

Tags: history, m4

Ok, I admit, it's been a long time since I've used m4.  Like, the last time I really did anything with it was on Seventh Edition Unix...

I was somewhat taken by surprise when I found that macros weren't being expanded on lines that started with a '#' character.  This is sort of inconvenient when using m4 to generate Markdown...  After some research, I found that the '#' character is a comment delimiter.  When did this get added to the language? I've been using the original Kernighan and Ritchie paper on m4 as my reference, clearly this is out of date now...  But I haven't been able to find any information on when this was added.

Related to that, what is the comment feature in m4 actually useful for?  Comments are just passed through to the output (including the comment character) without expanding macros within the comment.  I could understand if this was used to put a comment into a source file that's ignored and not passed through (the way you can do using 'dnl'), but I'm having a hard time imagining what this could be useful for as implemented.

Comment: Not an answer, but you can turn off comments with [`changecom`](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/html_node/Changecom.html).

Comment: Comments seem to predate the POSIX specification of m4. The [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/m4.html) includes comments and `changecom`, but it doesn't say anything about comments in the change history.

Comment: changecom (# is default) is defined in my System 3.0 manual (June 1980)